# React.js translate component not showing on the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I am trying to create a web app in which user search for a word using 'Form' component and then the result is fetched from an API and then passed to 'translate' component, but my 'translate' component is not showing in the browser.**

**form.jsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./form.scss";
import Translate from "./translate"

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: "",
            getdata: []
        }
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };
    componentDidMount() {

    }
    submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { term } = this.state;
        const rawUrl="https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term="+term;
        const url=rawUrl;
        fetch(url, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "c8cb6b8cccmshc02b57f0b5a8c98p1516cdjsnb64d72a5ad33"
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data=>{
                this.setState({getdata:[data.list]});
                console.log(this.state.getdata);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
    render() {
        const translate=this.state.getdata.map(item => (<Translate word={item.word} definition={item.definition} />))
        return (
            <div class="full">
                {translate}
                <div class="searchForm">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="term" value={this.state.term} placeholder="Enter a word here" onChange={this.handleChange}></input><button onClick={this.submit}>Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Form;
```

**translate.jsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./translate.css";

class Translate extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="all">
                <div class="single">
                    <div class="word">
                        {this.props.word}
                    </div>
                    <div class="def">
                        {this.props.definition}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Translate;
```

Can anyone solve this error.
I am stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: only one problem i can see is your translate variable change it as follows  const translate=<>{this.state.getdata.map(item => (<Translate word={item.word} definition={item.definition} />))}</>

Comment: map returns multiple items so it needs to be encapsulated in one component. This could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're saving the array returned by the API call within another array `this.setState({getdata:[data.list]});`. This is making it difficult to parse. Below is a working example which has been simplified due to limited access to your css files:

**Form.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Translate from "./Translate";

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: "",
      getdata: []
    };
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  componentDidMount() {}
  submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { term } = this.state;
    const rawUrl =
      "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=" +
      term;
    const url = rawUrl;
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "c8cb6b8cccmshc02b57f0b5a8c98p1516cdjsnb64d72a5ad33"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("DATA", data.list);
        this.setState({ getdata: data.list });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  render() {
    const translate = this.state.getdata.map((item) => (
      <Translate
        word={item.word}
        definition={item.definition}
        key={item.defid}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="term"
              value={this.state.term}
              placeholder="Enter a word here"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            ></input>
            <button onClick={this.submit}>Search</button>
          </form>
          {translate}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Form;
```

**Translate.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Translate(props) {
  const { word, definition } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>{word}</div>
        <div>{definition}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Working Example]